# hector_localization

Tags: ros, hector-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I already compiled and build the hector_localization package. And everything is fine. I would like to use is with the odometry and IMU. But dont know how. Which parameters should I set and what lunch file do I need?Is there any help¿¿¿¿

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53365/hector_localization/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess the first thing you can do is follow the link below:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot

Then what you have to figure out is the correct frame name, also make sure they are published correctly.

---

Originally posted by [bona](https://answers.ros.org/users/1158/bona/) with karma: 101 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1